# Why don't moderators follow their own rules they impose us?

Tags: discussion

I am curious about this [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/175663/elevation-word-usage).

According to Meta guidebook, and and according to the new CoC,

Comments should be

[image]

[image]

The comments there do not belong to the new CoC ( At least, the first commenter says **Wikipedia says "The eastern Deccan Plateau is at a lower elevation spanning the southeastern coast of India.** ) which is **almost an answer**.

And the comment does not follow the comment guideline by Meta.

I flagged, since a moderator says,

> @KentaroT - Perhaps a better solution is to simply accept that many comments get deleted. I don't know what you mean by "so-called establishment classes," but I just combed through some statistics – the four moderators themselves have had well over 3000 of their comments deleted. Our #1 user, the revered StoneyB, has had over 1000 comments deleted. Comments are meant to be temporary by design. (As an aside, it's interesting how the help pages list three reasons why you should comment, but six reasons that you shouldn't.)

Yes, only mines were deleted right after "commenting".

The first and most important thing should have been **not a commenting** but **answering** ( according to them. )

Why did moderators delete my comments but not encourage the commentors to alter to answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your comments were deleted because they did not contribute to the conversation at all. But let's take a look at those comments and digest a little further:

> I flagged the comment of Weather Vane as the violation against the more stringent ( in my personal opinion ) Code Of Conduct applied the day before. It clearly states "Wikipedia says...." is against "Be Nice policy".

First off, your assertion here is just false. The unfriendly example of "You could Google this in 5 seconds" is considered unfriendly because it just points you to go look somewhere else, with the implied tone that you are wasting the person's time and you aren't welcome here. The point is that there is much friendlier way of saying that, by providing relevant information (e.g. a term to search for) and using a nicer tone.

Simply including a description of something from an alternate source doesn't really come anywhere close to that example. The user didn't just rudely tell the user to go look at Wikipedia, and the comment in no way implied anything unfriendly. They just provided a description that might be relevant to the question. We're certainly not going to ban references to Wikipedia.

**Even if it had been unfriendly**, your comment is still not worth posting. Nothing constructive comes from you pointing out to the user that you flagged them (even more so when your reasoning is invalid). It often just fans flames, which may not have even been ignited before the comment. If you have something constructive to say that helps the *question*, by all means, but don't go around telling people when you've flagged their stuff. Just flag it and leave it to moderators to deal with.

> And James clearly stated that answer should not be at the comment line. These comments should be removed or answered.

Your first line there doesn't make much sense, because James didn't say anything of the sort (at least not on this question - maybe you're referencing something else). That aside, if you think the comments make sense as an answer, simply state that you think these comments would make a good answer and ask if those users would like to move them. Provide explanation - don't just say "move them."

> Even the mods do not follow their own rule they impose us, their words are garbage.

This one is unfriendly in and of itself. For someone who is linking to the Code of Conduct as a reason to flag an earlier comment, it is a bit ironic that you would then write something like that yourself. It is clearly not in line with the very Code of Conduct you are trying to enforce.

---

Past that, not all of the comments actually appear to be attempts at answering. Most of the information shared there appears to be trying to figure out what the line is actually talking about, because it's not entirely clear. I'm not sure what kind of answer you'd expect to come out of those comments, but if there is one, it would likely be very short and lacking detail based on what was provided. Literally one of the comments asks "What book?" because they'd like to look into it to get a better understanding of the context, but you still flagged it as belonging in an answer. It very clearly doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 9):

Interestingly enough, in this particular instance, none of your comments were deleted by ELL mods. Evidently, you've managed to attract the attention of some SE mods, who deleted your comments before anyone from the ELL mod team even had a chance to investigate your flags. What's more, you posted your meta question here before we had taken any action, either. So, it looks like an SE mod rightly deleted your outburst, and then you immediately came here and renewed your accusations toward the ELL mod team even before they knew what had happened.

Flags are designed to help the community improve and police itself. Sadly, it looks like you are less interested in helping the site maintain its high standards, and more interested in finding some "gotcha" comparison so you can somehow prove or confirm a longstanding belief that you have been treated unfairly. Such tactics rarely help forge goodwill and support within the community.

I'd suggest letting bygones be bygones, and focus on making more productive posts, rather than staying enraged about previously deleted comments.